# Create vba loop to index checkbox and columns

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

View the following code, instead of repetitive lines, I want to loop this to save time...

```
'show/hide SN# DEFECTIVE
    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    If CheckBox2.Value = False Then Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

'show/hide SN# INSTALLED
    If CheckBox3.Value = True Then Columns("g").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    If CheckBox3.Value = False Then Columns("g").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

'show/hide SN# DESCRIPTION
    If CheckBox4.Value = True Then Columns("h").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    If CheckBox4.Value = False Then Columns("h").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

'show/hide SN# DESCRIPTION
    If CheckBox4.Value = True Then Columns("h").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    If CheckBox4.Value = False Then Columns("h").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

I have the following, which works great...

```
For i = 2 To 4
     chk = Me.Controls("checkbox" & i).Value
        MsgBox "checkbox " & i & " " & chk

            If chk = False Then
                Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Else
                    Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
           End If

Next i
```

However, I also want to index the columns as well, but these are identified as "letters", so how can I also increment an "f" to the next letter "g", and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use loop for this unless you have many more columns to change visibility.

However, what I would do is definitely avoid Ifs and simply use the associate checkboxes' value's opposite to be set as the hidden property value like below. More readable, maintainable and of course shorter.

```
Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = Not CheckBox2.Value
Columns("g").EntireColumn.Hidden = Not CheckBox3.Value
Columns("h").EntireColumn.Hidden = Not CheckBox4.Value
```

EDIT: I don't recommend this but to provide you an answer for your question in your way: use Chr function to return letters.

```
For i = 2 To 4
    chk = Me.Controls("checkbox" & i).Value
    MsgBox "checkbox " & i & " " & chk
        If chk = False Then
            Columns(chr(100+i)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            Columns(chr(100+i)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
Next i
```

even shorter using my way:

```
For i = 2 To 4
    Columns(chr(100+i)).EntireColumn.Hidden = Not Me.Controls("checkbox" & i).Value
Next i
```

Comment: wow, thanks a million, these options have sparked possibilities for me...humbly grateful for your time.

Comment: @DjrileyFdkns great to hear it helps! You're welcome. So it is now time to click on the Accept As Answer button to mark the effort as an answer. Have great 2017!